# Speech to text api - use morethen 1min audio using rest api show error

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-speech

When i select audio morethen 30sec or 1min then its show below error

--> Sync input too long. For audio longer than 1 min use LongRunningRecognize with a 'uri' parameter.

```
-> https://speech.googleapis.com/v1p1beta1/speech:recognize?key="api key"

body -> {
"audio":{"content":" // base64 formated audio // "},
"config":{
    "enableAutomaticPunctuation":true,
    "encoding":"WEBM_OPUS",
    "sampleRateHertz": 16000,
    "languageCode":"en-US",
    "model":"default"
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `speech:longrunningrecognize` endpoint for audio longer than 1 minute.

The endpoint with `key` is `https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:longrunningrecognize?key="api_key"`

Using curl I can send a request to this endpoint:

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:longrunningrecognize?key=AIzaSyD....\
   -d "{
  'config': {
    'language_code': 'en-US'
  },
  'audio':{
    'uri':'gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac'
  }
}"
```

Output:

```
{
  "name": "1521059426290567438"
}
```

When a request is sent to the endpoint, it will create a long running operation and it will return a `name`. This will be used to check the status of the long running operation. You can check the status by sending a request to this endpoint `https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/operations/<name>`. If the operation is done, it will return the transcript in the response.

Check status:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
     "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/operations/1521059426290567438?key=AIzaSyD...."
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: FLAC encode work with you provided link but i have file format .aac so encoding type flac not work for it can you help for this?